# Crear un triángulo alineado a la izquerda

Tags: javascript, typescript, ordenamiento

En un ejercicio de HackerRank encontré este ejercicio, se trata de imprimir N veces el carácter #, pero de derecha a izquierda.

Esa fue mi solución, pero al parecer la orientación es importante

```js
function staircase(n: number): void {
    // Write your code here
    
    let item = "#"
    
    for(let i=0; i<=n; i++){
        console.log(`${item.repeat(i)}`)
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Algún método, función o algoritmo de ordenamiento que me pueda ayudar con este problema?

Comment: Normalmente en el chat de discusion de "Hacker Rank" suele haber tanto explicación como solución a estos problemas.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar [`padStart()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) para rellenar con espacios a la izquerda y con esto dar la alineación correcta. El total de espacios no debe superar a `n` por lo que ese será tu límite (el método `padStart()` colocará la cadena hasta alcanzar la longitud).

```js
function staircase(n) {
  let item = "#";

  for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    console.log(item.repeat(i).padStart(n))
  }
}

staircase(5);
```

Tampoco es necesario hacer uso de plantillas literales puesto que por el tipo de operación podrías hacerlo directamente. Adicionalmente tienes que empezar en `1`, porque si empiezas en `0` obtendrás esa línea vacía del inicio.